# Rewrite URLs with different domains and similar paths

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all URLs formatted as `http://www.example.org/dir/subdir/` to `http://subdomain.example.org/subdir/`. For example, `http://www.example.org/dir/subdir/page` would redirect to `http://subdomain.example.org/subdir/page`.

I tried `rewrite ^(/dir/subdir.*) http://subdomain.example.org$1 permanent;`, but this keeps the `/dir/` part, which I want to omit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is capturing the /dir/ part too. 
Try this:

```
location /dir/subdir {
    rewrite ^/dir(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.org$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much!